# Is sky-glow affected by height?

Tags: telescope, space, night-sky, space-telescope, light-pollution

I'm an architecture student and my graduation project will consist of building a research center for outer space, my question is whether or not height would affect [sky-glow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyglow) or not ? Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to astronomy SE! I made some small edits to make your question more concise.

Answer (score 4):

Sky-glow is a generic term for the diffuse light not due to the sun, moon or stars (or aurorae, I suppose). Much of it is light pollution from the ground, some is the zodiacal light from dust in space, and the coolest part may arguably be the air-glow from chemical reactions in the upper atmosphere.

So, depending on height the different components would change strength. Urban light pollution apparently declines as $\propto d^{-2.5}$ (["Walker's law"](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/130142)) due to spreading and absorption, so it would decline with altitude. The zodiacal light would get stronger with less absorption in the atmosphere. The [air glow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airglow) is altitude-dependent, and would presumably intensify at first, until one is above it (like the ISS) is.